# Facebook app shows different permission boxes

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, permissions, facebook-login

I just set up a website to login with a Facebook-account. Everything is working and we are in  test mode now. Yesterday my tester let me know that, when he wants to register to the website via Facebook he gets a different permissionbox then his friend.

Testers box: [box tester](http://reinvanleirsberghe.be/images/box1.jpg)

Friends box: [box friend](http://reinvanleirsberghe.be/images/box2.jpg)
How is that possible and how can I change that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your friends sees is the “old” Auth dialog that Facebook used until now – and it is in the process of being replaced by the new one, which your tester sees.

(See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/#login-dialog for description and pictures of the new dialog on different platforms/devices.)

Since this is still in roll-out phase, different users might get to see different versions (old/new) for a while, until roll-out is complete and it’ll be the new one for everyone.

Unlike when FB changed the Auth dialog last time, now there is no migration setting that I know of that would allow an app to “opt-in” for the new one explicitly.